# Is the ring of integers of a DVR also a DVR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

> $R$ is a DVR and $L$ is a finite separable extension of $Q(R)$. Can we say that the ring of integers is a DVR?

I know it's a Dedekind domain. So showing it's local is enough.

If it's not a DVR, what is a counterexample?

Comment: If you assume that $R$ is a complete DVR, then I think that the ring of integers is again a complete DVR but I am not very sure of this fact.

Comment: We say "integral closure of $R$ in $L$" not "ring of integers". @Soumik

Comment: A similar counter-example is $R=\Bbb{Z}_{(5)}, L= \Bbb{Q}(i)$ the integral closure is the intersection of two DVR $\Bbb{Z}[i]_{(2+i)}\cap \Bbb{Z}[i]_{(2-i)}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to construct a counter example.
Consider the integral extension $\mathbb C[X]\subset \mathbb C[X,Y]/\langle Y^2-X\rangle $ given by $X\mapsto \bar X$. This corresponds to the finite morphism of affine varieties $$ V=V(Y^2-X)\subset \mathbb A^2_C\rightarrow\mathbb A^1_\mathbb C$$ $$(z_1,z_2) \mapsto z_1$$
Now $1$ is a smooth point in $\mathbb A^1_\mathbb C$. So the local ring at $1$, $R$ is a DVR. Also $C[X]\subset \Gamma(V)$ is integral so $\Gamma(V)_m:=\left (\mathbb C[X]\backslash m \right )^{-1}\Gamma(V)$ is integral over $R=\mathbb C[X]_m$ where $m=(X-1)\mathbb C[X]$. So the ring of integers of $\mathbb C[X]$ in $\operatorname{Frac}(\Gamma(V))$  is an integral extension of $\Gamma(V)_m$. But $\Gamma(V)_m$ already contains two distinct maximal ideals namely $\langle X-1,Y\pm 1\rangle$. So the integral closure cannot be local either and hence ain't a DVR.

Comment: Your construction is correct but the notations  $m=(X-1)$ (in what ring?), $\mathbb C[X]_m$ and $\Gamma[V]_m$ together are a bit misleading since $m$ is not an ideal of $\Gamma[V]$. Also,  it would be better not to use the same letters $X,Y$ in a polynomial ring and in its quotient. Those "abus de langage" wouldn't matter in a professional context but the site is not dedicated only to specialists in commutative algebra.

Comment: I have edited the notation.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.